# problems with JDateChooser

Tags: java, jframe, jdatechooser

I just started my first complex java program, which is a bank system program. I want to check if    the user is an adult or not. I added a JDateChooser to the frame, i can choose a date, but my problem is  that i can not take only the year.

```
`import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.util.*;

 JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
 public boolean isAdult() {

            Date date = new Date();
            int currentYear = date.getYear();
            int clientYear;

            if (dateChooser.toString().length() > 4) {
                clientYear =         Integer.parseInt(dateChooser.toString().substring(dateChooser.toString().length() - 4));
                System.out.println(clientYear);
            } else {
                clientYear = Integer.parseInt(date.toString());
            }
            int age = currentYear - clientYear;
            if (age < 18) {
                return false;
            } else return true;
        }``
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to read just the year from the JDateChooser.

To do this easily, use the `getDate()` method of the JDateChooser. It will return an instance of [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html). You can then use the method [`getYear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#getYear()) to get the year of type `int`